# GET URL link from uploaded image to dropbox with SDK

Tags: iphone, metadata, response, dropbox

Uploading images to a folder using the SDK I would like to get the original link to the image.  I have searched the the metaData from DMMetaData using the method below. There are several methods owned by DBMetaData such as "root" and "content" but I always recieve a Null response. If anyone could possibly lead me in the right direction to grab that information from the response that would be greatly appreciated!

```
-(void)uploadImage:(UIImage *)image{

[sounds PlayUploading:nil];

NSLog(@"upload from uploader!~");
NSData *data = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image);
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, 
NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *path = [[paths objectAtIndex:0] stringByAppendingString:@"PreviewMaker.png"];

[restClient setDelegate:self];


[data writeToFile:path atomically:YES];
[[self restClient] uploadFile:@"PreviewMaker.png" toPath:@"/"
                withParentRev:nil fromPath:path]; 



 }


 -(void)restClient:(DBRestClient *)client uploadedFile:(NSString *)destPath 
 from:(NSString *)srcPath metadata:(DBMetadata *)metadata{

 NSLog(@"uploaded: %@ from %@ withData %@",destPath,srcPath,metadata.root);

}
```

Comment: NSString *localPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"MyContacts copy" ofType:@"json"];
    NSString *filename = @"MyContacts";
    NSString *destDir = @"/";
    
    [[self restClient] uploadFile:filename toPath:destDir
                    withParentRev:nil fromPath:localPath];

Comment: - (void)restClient:(DBRestClient*)client uploadedFile:(NSString*)destPath
              from:(NSString*)srcPath metadata:(DBMetadata*)metadata {
    
    NSLog(@"File uploaded successfully to path: %@", metadata.path);
}

Comment: I have my uploading methods taken care of and have edited my initial question to reflect this. I also know I can grab the "metaData.Path" and other objects owned by "DBMetaDeta" but what I really need is the URL its creates such as " https://www.dropbox.com/s/oumn2g8zthohcpm/PreviewMaker%20%2824%29.png " If anyone can point me in the right direction how to grab this URL after an image is uploaded I would be very grateful ~ Thank you

Comment: Do you need the sharable link of that image ?

Comment: Yes I would like the sharable "original" link if possible....

Comment: Just a min please ., Will direct you to the right way !

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To get a sharable link for a file in DropBox !

There is a method in DBRestClient.h that you should take a look at!

```
- (void)loadSharableLinkForFile:(NSString *)path;
```

and their delegate Methods as well!!

```
- (void)restClient:(DBRestClient*)restClient loadedSharableLink:(NSString*)link 
forFile:(NSString*)path;
- (void)restClient:(DBRestClient*)restClient loadSharableLinkFailedWithError:(NSError*)error;
```

example : let us consider i have a file MyContacts in my Dropbox 
then to share it ,

```
[[self restClient] loadSharableLinkForFile:@"/MyContacts"];
```

and their delegate methods

```
- (void)restClient:(DBRestClient*)restClient loadedSharableLink:(NSString*)link 
           forFile:(NSString*)path
{

    NSLog(@"Sharable link %@",link);
    NSLog(@"File Path %@ ",path);
}

- (void)restClient:(DBRestClient*)restClient loadSharableLinkFailedWithError:(NSError*)error
{
    NSLog(@"Error %@",error);
}
```

Comment: and you should know that these sharable links will expire with some time interval

Comment: Thank you I appreciate the help! I have now got the link needed. They expire? I guess I can check if they are valid later in the app if need be and create new ones if needed now I am able to do that. Thank you I saw these methods just didnt understand them fully and now just call  [self.restClient loadSharableLinkForFile:destPath]; during the -(void)restClient:(DBRestClient *)client uploadedFile:(NSString *)destPath 
 from:(NSString *)srcPath metadata:(DBMetadata *)metadata

Comment: Thank you and yes exactly you are on the right way :) and they say [these sharable links expires](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/reference/api#shares)