# How do I share documents using dropbox Api in iPhone app?

Tags: iphone, ios, dropbox, dropbox-api

I am writing an app for iOS using dropbox Api.
My app has the following features,
1. User must be able to log in to his dropbox account, create document and upload.
2. He must be able to view his folder and file contents.
3. User must have the provision to share the documents with others.

I have completed the first 2 tasks, but finding it difficult to share the documents. I have referred dropbox developers forum but didn't get any solution.
Can anybody please tell me how do I do this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I came to know from some resources that APPLE is rejecting apps integrating DORPBOX SDK

Comment: @hpiOSCoder actually dropbox recently updated its API and the new apps using the updated version successfully passed the review

Comment: @Akhil Nair [Here is the code to share documents with others](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10564227/1059705)

Answer (score 11):

You can make a call to:

```
NSString *path = @"/yourfile.jpg";
[[self restClient] loadSharableLinkForFile:path];
```

Then you set up the delegate methods:

```
- (void)restClient:(DBRestClient*)restClient loadedSharableLink:(NSString*)link forFile:(NSString*)path
{
    NSLog(@"link is %@", link);
}
- (void)restClient:(DBRestClient*)restClient loadSharableLinkFailedWithError:(NSError*)error
{    
    NSLog("%@", [error localizedDescription]); 
}
```

You can find all the calls you need by looking inside the framework at DBRestClient.h.

Good luck!

Comment: Also if you would like a short-url, you can call the method: 

 [[self restClient] loadSharableLinkForFile:path shortUrl:YES];

Comment: Short URLs appear to be the default.  If you need a *long* URL, e.g so "?dl=1" can be appended to it for direct downloading, you need to use the short URL method @Will mentions with shortURL set to "NO": [[self restClient] loadSharableLinkForFile:path shortUrl:NO];

Answer (score 2):

The Dropbox API provides the /shares call ( https://www.dropbox.com/developers/reference/api#shares ) to allow you to create read-only shareable links ( https://www.dropbox.com/help/167 ) to any file or folder in the user's Dropbox. This call is available via the loadSharableLinkForFile: function in DBRestClient.m in the official Dropbox iOS SDK. (The Dropbox API does not currently offer any calls for read/write shared folders.)