# How to download a Dropbox share linkage (aimed at a zip file) to local

Tags: ios, dropbox, dropbox-api

I have following question and want help regarding that.I'm using Dropbox iOS SDK.

Is it possible to download a Dropbox share linkage (aimed at a zip file) like https://www.dropbox.com/s/m2o28nls8m8uyx9/FacebookAPI.zip.

I think I could use HTTP post method. However, the receive MIME Type is text/html rather than zip type.

Thanks

Comment: so you need a sharable link of your files in dropbox right? then kindly take a look at my answer here [Sharable Links](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10564227/1059705)

Comment: I can create my share linkage. My question is how to download the share linkage (aimed a zip file) and save the zip file on my iPhone device.

Comment: By the way, it seems that loadSharableLinkForFile is kind of mapping and encapsulation to its http post method (https://www.dropbox.com/developers/reference/api#shares). That is to say, I can use HTTP POST or loadSharableLinkForFile to do function of "share link". Is that right?

Comment: Yes. but still i dint understand your question ? and if you are going to explain me,update that in your question itself.

Comment: I am suffering the same thing now...Liang Wang means that he wants to download the zip file directly by using the DropBox SDK. But the sharable link generated directs people to a html, not the zip file itself. (If you try to download the zip file in a browser by right-clicking the mouse and select "Save the link as", you will have a html instead of a real zip file

Answer (score 7, accepted):

i think you can try this:
change your sharable link to:
https://dl.dropbox.com/s/m2o28nls8m8uyx9/FacebookAPI.zip?dl=1

it works on my file.

Answer (score 1):

For me this works

Replace 'https://www.dropbox.com' with 'https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com'