# Downloading a file from Dropbox in Android

Tags: android, download, dropbox

Well I need to download an a image from internet for application splash screen.After read [this doc](https://www.dropbox.com/help/201/en). I see Dropbox has a perfect solution for direct download file.

if I use my server its okay but if I want to use Dropbox share file link it gives error. the error is:

```
05-03 10:12:32.410: W/System.err(20373): java.net.UnknownHostException: Unable to resolve host "www.dropbox.com": No address associated with hostname
```

and also this is my shared link

> https://www.dropbox.com/s/ixk2tkokmtaqu62/reklam.png

and those are my tried but NOT succeed links

> https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/ixk2tkokmtaqu62/reklam.png
>   and
>   https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/ixk2tkokmtaqu62/reklam.png?dl=1

Comment: okay I have found solition from [here][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14259663/2677801

Comment: So, what happens, if your user is not connected?

Comment: Actually I don't understand wht you mean. This is just a link. Download a file from URL

Comment: I mean that not always your user are connected to internet. Are they necessarily?

Comment: Yeah you right it needs internet