# Swift - Downloaded zip file creating .cpgz file after extract.

Tags: ios, swift

Downloading a zip file from Dropbox or Google drive URL results in a zip file that is extracted to cpgz file. Using below code to accomplish download of zip file. I want to know is there any specific way to download any zip file so that it does not result in cpgz cycle.

```
if let zipUrl = URL(string: "https://www.dropbox.com/s/n785nwy2tbaxgz8/app_dfu_package_1.zip?dl=0") {
        // create your document folder url
        let documentsUrl = try! FileManager.default.url(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask, appropriateFor: nil, create: true)
        // your destination file url
        let destination = documentsUrl.appendingPathComponent(zipUrl.lastPathComponent)
        //print(destination)

        var urlRequest = URLRequest.init(url: zipUrl)
        urlRequest.httpMethod = "get"
        urlRequest.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "content-Type")

        // check if it exists before downloading it
        if FileManager().fileExists(atPath: destination.path) {
            print("The file already exists at path")
        } else {
            //  if the file doesn't exist just download the data from your url
            URLSession.shared.downloadTask(with: urlRequest, completionHandler: { (location, response, error) in
                // after downloading your data you need to save it to your destination url
                guard
                    let httpURLResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse, httpURLResponse.statusCode == 200,
                    let location = location, error == nil
                    else { return }
                do {
                    try FileManager.default.moveItem(at: location, to: destination)
                    print("file saved")
                } catch {
                    print(error)
                }
            }).resume()
        }
    }
```

How we can fix it in Swift code

Comment: If you get a cpgz file then either the zip file is corrupt or the download wasn't completed when you tried to unzip it.

Comment: When I download the file normally, it works fine. After download success, I am getting file saved message on the console. You can check the file is not corrupted by downloading it. How do I get it correctly while downloading via URLSession download task?

Comment: There is no data in your request, why are you setting `content-type` to JSON? Are you handling authorization correctly? The URL is not even a direct download link. When opened in browser, it displays a web page with contents of the file.

Answer (score 0):

Sharing the link that solved my issue. I was also getting zip file's mime type text/html. Changing the dropbox url solved my query.

> [How to download a Dropbox share linkage (aimed at a zip file) to local](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13759882/how-to-download-a-dropbox-share-linkage-aimed-at-a-zip-file-to-local)

```
if let zipUrl = URL(string: "https://www.dropbox.com/s/n785nwy2tbaxgz8/app_dfu_package_1.zip?dl=1") {
        // create your document folder url
        let documentsUrl = try! FileManager.default.url(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask, appropriateFor: nil, create: true)
        // your destination file url
        let destination = documentsUrl.appendingPathComponent(zipUrl.lastPathComponent)
        //print(destination)

        var urlRequest = URLRequest.init(url: zipUrl)
        urlRequest.httpMethod = "get"
        urlRequest.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "content-Type")

        // check if it exists before downloading it
        if FileManager().fileExists(atPath: destination.path) {
            print("The file already exists at path")
        } else {
            //  if the file doesn't exist just download the data from your url
            URLSession.shared.downloadTask(with: urlRequest, completionHandler: { (location, response, error) in
                // after downloading your data you need to save it to your destination url
                guard
                    let httpURLResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse, httpURLResponse.statusCode == 200,
                    let mimeType = response?.mimeType,
                    let location = location, error == nil
                    else { return }
                do {
                    try FileManager.default.moveItem(at: location, to: destination)
                    print("file saved")
                    print("Mime Type:- \(mimeType)")
                } catch {
                    print(error.localizedDescription)
                }
            }).resume()
        }
    }
```

After making URL change(dl=0 to dl=1), the mime type I get is application/binary. It solved .zip to .cpgz cycles on the extraction of the zip file.

Answer (score 0):

First make sure that your server is returning a zip file itself or not by adding following code :

```
let response = response as! HTTPURLResponse  
guard (200...299).contains(response.statusCode) else {  
    … deal with the server-side error …  
}  
guard response.mimeType == "application/zip" else {  
    … deal with the bogus `Content-Type` …  
}
```

If its a zip file then it will execute forward and you have to do like follows to save that file in disk:

```
let destinationDir = try! FileManager.default.url(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask, appropriateFor: nil, create: true)
            let destination = destinationDir.appendingPathComponent("SomeFileName.zip")
            try data!.write(to: destination)
```